# How can I extract values from a list of objects based on a property of these objects?

Tags: java, list, collections

I'd like to find objects in a list based on having a certain property.

For example, say I have a list of objects of this class:

```
class Person {
    private String name;
    private String id;
}
```

I know that I can get *all* of the names of people in the list by using:

```
Collection<String> names = CollectionUtils.collect(
    personList,
    TransformerUtils.invokerTransformer("getName"));
```

but what I want to do is get a list of the `Person` objects whose name is, for example, `"Nick"`. I don't have Java 8.

Comment: What is wrong with simply iterating through the list and checking each name?

Comment: iterate the list using a for statement, inside check if the name equals 'Nick' and if so then add the object to another list

Comment: for loops and if statements are always there.

Comment: even better would but probably not as performant as a for look would be using the filter in the java 8 streaming API.
something like `List<Person> nicks = personList.stream.filter(person-> "Nick".equals(person.getName()).collect(Collectors.toList())`

Comment: Why use a collection to do this when you can simply iterate  through the list and check with if an statement if the name is 'Nick'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see you are using Apache Common Utils, then you can use:

```
CollectionUtils.filter( personList, new Predicate<Person>() {
    @Override
    public boolean evaluate( Person p ) {
        return p.getName() != null && p.getName().equals( "Nick" );
    }
});
```

Comment: `return "Nick".equals(p.getName());`

Comment: Apache collection utils provides the method to transform a trasformer into a predicate, so the anonymous class is not necessary (assuming the OP is willing to use reflect as indicated by his code sample).

Comment: @svasa Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use Java 8 streams, simply loop through the list and check the elements manually:

```
ArrayList<Person> filteredList = new ArrayList<Person>();

for(Person person : personList) {
    if(person.getName().equals("Nick")) filteredList.add(person);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Using Apache collection utils (which you are already using), you can use the `filter` method which creates a subset of your collection consisting of items which match a given filter, combined with a `Predicate` that matches "Nick" based on your `Transformer` and `transformedPredicate`:

```
CollectionUtils.filter(names, PredicateUtils.transformedPredicate(
    TransformerUtils.invokerTransformer("getName"), PredicateUtils.equalPredicate("Nick")));
```

That said, you may want to reconsider using such a heavily functional approach before you migrate to Java 8. Not only will you have a lot of redundant Apache collections code after you migrate, the solutions prior to the introduction of closures and lambdas tend to be verbose and often less readable than the imperative alternatives.

*Note:* this modifies the existing collection in-place. If that is not the desired behavior, you'll need to create a copy before calling the filter method.

Comment: your code seems to remove all the results not just the one that I want to extract

Comment: It should work, although there may be a bug (I didn't try it). Can you post a SSCCE that shows it not working?

Comment: Sure thing. I'll post it in a while.

Comment: I actually figured out why it was not working. Your code is absolutely correct. Thanks a lot. Upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a HashMap.

```
HashMap<String, Integer> points = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    points.put("Amy", 154);
    points.put("Dave", 42);
    points.put("Rob", 733);
    System.out.println(points.get("Dave"));
```

This would only be an example, but you could check and instead of having the String, Integer, you could try Integer, String and have an `if statement`. Just an idea though.

Answer (score 0):

I am considering that you might have a collection of different objects that have this property name. For that I would recommend you to do parent for those components and perform the search on it with generics:

For example:

Parent class Name.java

```
public class Name {

    private String name;

    public Name(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Class Pet.java

```
public class Pet extends Name{

    public Pet(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

}
```

And class Person.java

```
public class Person extends Name{

    public Person(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

}
```

Job class that doesn't have the property:

```
public class Job {

    private String description;

    public Job(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

}
```

Having that, you can check the instance of it and compare what you want:

```
public static void main(String ... args) {
    List<Object> objectList = new ArrayList();
    objectList.add(new Person("Nick"));
    objectList.add(new Person("Nik"));
    objectList.add(new Person("Nikc"));
    objectList.add(new Person("Ncik"));
    objectList.add(new Pet("Nick"));
    objectList.add(new Pet("Nik"));
    objectList.add(new Pet("Nikc"));
    objectList.add(new Pet("Ncik"));
    objectList.add(new Job("Nick"));
    objectList.add(new Job("Nik"));
    objectList.add(new Job("Nikc"));
    objectList.add(new Job("Ncik"));

    for (Object o : extractObjectsMatching("Nick", objectList)){
        System.out.println(((Name) o).getName());
    }
}

public static List<Object> extractObjectsMatching(String name, List<Object> objectList){
    List<Object> matches = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Object e : objectList){
        if (e instanceof Name && ((Name) e).getName().contains(name)){
            matches.add(e);
        }
    }

    return matches;
}
```

If the Object class is not an instance of Name, means that will not have the property that you are looking for, just ignore, otherwise, compare with the information that you want and store to retrieve.